How to call python functions compiled to C in C++ (Cython)?
Problem
Everybody extends python with C, but I need opposite scenario. I want to use code in C++ project.
Cythonize
It kinda works. I did convert simple .pyx file to .c using Cython.
Function is super simple with only print.
# hello_cython.pyx
def func1():
    print("Hello Cython Function.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Hello World! Run cython.")


Setup.py just for reference (if needed)
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize


# my_extension = Extension('SayHiApp',)

setup(
    name="AppHi",
    ext_modules=cythonize("hello_cython.pyx", show_all_warnings=True),  

To replicate
Use python setup.py build_ext --inplace
This will create C file.
Short example from 5000 lines:
/* Generated by Cython 3.0.10 */

/* BEGIN: Cython Metadata
{
    "distutils": {
        "name": "hello_cython",
        "sources": [
            "hello_cython.pyx"
        ]
    },
    "module_name": "hello_cython"
}
END: Cython Metadata */

#ifndef PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#endif /* PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN */
#if defined(CYTHON_LIMITED_API) && 0
  #ifndef Py_LIMITED_API
    #if CYTHON_LIMITED_API+0 > 0x03030000
      #define Py_LIMITED_API CYTHON_LIMITED_API
    #else
      #define Py_LIMITED_API 0x03030000
    #endif
  #endif
#endif

#include "Python.h"
#ifndef Py_PYTHON_H
    #error Python headers needed to compile C extensions, please install development version of Python.
#elif PY_VERSION_HEX < 0x02070000 || (0x03000000 <= PY_VERSION_HEX && PY_VERSION_HEX < 0x03030000)
    #error Cython requires Python 2.7+ or Python 3.3+.
#else
#if defined(CYTHON_LIMITED_API) && CYTHON_LIMITED_API
#define __PYX_EXTRA_ABI_MODULE_NAME "limited"
#else
#define __PYX_EXTRA_ABI_MODULE_NAME ""
#endif
#define CYTHON_ABI "3_0_10" __PYX_EXTRA_ABI_MODULE_NAME
#define __PYX_ABI_MODULE_NAME "_cython_" CYTHON_ABI
#define __PYX_TYPE_MODULE_PREFIX __PYX_ABI_MODULE_NAME "."
#define CYTHON_HEX_VERSION 0x03000AF0
#define CYTHON_FUTURE_DIVISION 1
#include <stddef.h>
#ifndef offsetof
  #define offsetof(type, member) ( (size_t) & ((type*)0) -> member )
#endif
#if !defined(_WIN32) && !defined(WIN32) && !defined(MS_WINDOWS)
  #ifndef __stdcall
    #define __stdcall
  #endif
  #ifndef __cdecl
    #define __cdecl
  #endif
  #ifndef __fastcall
    #define __fastcall
  #endif
#endif

C++ project
I attached generated .c file to C++ project, fixed missing hearder and libs. It finally compiles, without any errors or warnings (ignore errors on screenshot).
.cpp file is empty main function that does nothing.
// LearnPythonAPIIntegration.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    /// I want to call func1() here somehow

}

But how can I use it? I don't see any function that would look like defined by me.
Have I done something wrong? I just wonder maybe I can't reuse it and I should rewrite this in C++.

Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots (how to format code in posts). Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

You need to use extern "C" to reference C functions from C++.

This is documented in https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#using-cython-declarations-from-c

its 5000 lines, you really want me to just paste it here?

@GrzegorzKrug no, we want to to provide a [mcve] and then provide that as text in the question itself. Cool avatar, btw.

I gave you all files, just go with python setup.py build_ext --inplace it will create that file, i don't really know which part could I post

Just to summarise the documentation, you need to declare the function you want to call cdef public or cdef api to create a C header you can use it from. And you need to remember that it's part of a Python module, so initialize the interpreter and import the module.

If you want to call generic Python code from C++ though, I generally prefer PyBind11 - it's less intrusive than what you need to do with Cython.
